# Combinatorics Proof

Tags: combinatorics

Let $b_n$ be the number of positive integers whose digits are all $1,$ $3,$ or $4,$ and add up to $n$.

For example, $b_5 = 6$, since there are six integers with the desired property: $41,$ $14,$ $311,$ $131,$ $113,$ and $11111$.

Prove that $b_n$ is a perfect square if $n$ is even.

---

So I drew a few numerical examples for small values of $b_n$ but I haven't figured out a proof yet.

Comment: What does this have to do with Catalan numbers?

Comment: Looks like a change-counting type problem.

Comment: $b_n$ seems to be $\displaystyle\operatorname{round}\left(\frac{L_{n+2}}5\right)$, where $\operatorname{round}$ is the nearest-integer function and $L_n$ is the Lucas numbers (like Fibonacci but with $L_0=2$ and $L_1=1$).

Comment: Though that seems to be overkill. Experimentation shows that $b_{2n}=(F_{n+1})^2$, which is all you really need to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is straightforward to see that the $b_n$ are determined by the recurrence relation:
$$
b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-3} + b_{n-4}
$$
You can then prove that a solution is given by inductively setting $b_{n+4} = b_n + F_{n+4}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.  This yields, for instance
$$
\begin{align*}
b_8 &= F_8 + F_4 + 1\\
b_9 &= F_9 + F_5 + F_1\\
b_{10} &= F_{10} + F_6 + F_2\\
b_{11} &= F_{11} + F_7 + F_3\\
b_{12} &= F_{12} + F_8 + F_4 + 1
\end{align*}
$$ 
and the pattern continues similarly.  To prove the desired statement, you can inductively demonstrate the following two statements.
$$b_{2n} = F_{n+1}^2\\ b_{2n-1} = F_{n+1}F_n$$